# Hide tabPanel and subtabs in shiny based on reactive condition

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an app that I am working on that has multiple sets of subtabs. I need to show or hide a tab that has subtabs within it, based on a reactive value. For example, in the reprex below, I would like to show the 'Plots' tab (with Plot 1 and Plot 2 as subtabs) for either iris or mtcars, only if the permission_color() outputs *TRUE*. I want it to continue to dynamically show or hide based on continually changing the color input, not just for it to show up once when 'green' is chosen and then for it to stay there.

(In this app the permission reactive is based on a selectInput, but in my actual app it will be based on log in information using shinymanager as well as a drop down menu.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)






# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(

  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    
    sidebarMenu(id = "menume",
#selectInput("which unit", "Choose a unit", choices = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")),
 

    sidebarMenuOutput("colormenu"),
    menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
    selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars)),
    menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),
    selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("mt", uiOutput("mttabs")),
      tabItem("ir", uiOutput("irtabs"))
      )
      
    )
  



)




# ui <- secure_app(ui, enable_admin = TRUE)


# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$colormenu = renderMenu({
    # Remove the req
    selectInput("colorme", "Choose a color", c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"))
    
         
          })
  

  permission_color = reactive({
    if(input$colormenu =="green"){
      
      TRUE
    }else{
      
      FALSE
    }
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  output$mttabs = renderUI({
  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
    
    
  })
  
  output$mtcarsplot2=renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + geom_density()
    })
 
    
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    tabme= head(mtcars, 5)
    tabme

  
  })
  
  
  
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "mtcarstabsall",
              
              tabPanel("Tables",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "mttables",
              
              tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",value=1,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
              ))),
              tabPanel("Plots",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "mtplotsall",
              tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",value=2,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                       )),
              tabPanel(id = "mtplots2","mtcars plots 2",value=3,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("mtcarsplot2")))))
  
              ))
  })
  
  
  output$irtabs = renderUI({
  
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
    
    
  })
  
  output$irisplot2=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + geom_density()
    
    
  })
  
  

  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    tabme = head(iris, 5)
    tabme
  })
  
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "iristabsall",
              tabPanel("Tables",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "iristables",
              tabPanel(id = "irtable","iris tables",value=4,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
              ))),
              tabPanel("Plots",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "irisplotsall",
                    
              tabPanel(id = "irisplots","iris plots",value=5,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                       )),
              tabPanel(id = "irisplots2","iris plots 2",value=6,
                       fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("irisplot2"))
                       )))
              
              ))
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conditionalPanel` to show the appropriate `menuItems` in the sidebar, and then `updateTabItems` to show the associated tabItems.

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

options(warn=-1)
data(iris)
data(mtcars)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    
    sidebarMenu(id = "menume",
                sidebarMenuOutput("colormenu"),
                uiOutput("mytab")
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="mt", 
              tabsetPanel(id = "mtcarstabsall",
                          
                          tabPanel("Tables",
                                   tabsetPanel(id = "mttables",
                                               
                                               tabPanel(id = "mttable","MTcars tables",value=1,
                                                        fluidRow(box(width=10, title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("mtcarstable1")))
                                               ))),
                          tabPanel("Plots",
                                   tabsetPanel(id = "mtplotsall",
                                               tabPanel(id = "mtplots","mtcars plots",value=2,
                                                        fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("mtcarsplot1"))
                                                        )),
                                               tabPanel(id = "mtplots2","mtcars plots 2",value=3,
                                                        fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("mtcarsplot2")))))
                                   
                          ))
              ),
      tabItem(tabName="ir", 
              tabsetPanel(id = "iristabsall",
                          tabPanel("Tables",
                                   tabsetPanel(id = "iristables",
                                               tabPanel(id = "irtable","iris tables",value=4,
                                                        fluidRow(box(width=8, title = "Table 1",  tableOutput("iristable1")))
                                               ))),
                          tabPanel("Plots",
                                   tabsetPanel(id = "irisplotsall",
                                               
                                               tabPanel(id = "irisplots","iris plots",value=5,
                                                        fluidRow(box(title = "Plot1", plotOutput("irisplot1"))
                                                        )),
                                               tabPanel(id = "irisplots2","iris plots 2",value=6,
                                                        fluidRow(box(title = "Plot2", plotOutput("irisplot2"))
                                                        )))
                                   
                          ))
      )
    )
    
  )
  
)

# Begin Server ----------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$colormenu = renderMenu({
    selectInput("colorme", "Choose a color", c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"))
  })
  
  permission_color = reactive({
    if(input$colormenu =="green"){
      
      TRUE
    }else{
      
      FALSE
    }
    
  })
  
  output$mytab <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.colorme=="green"',
                       menuItem("MTCARS", tabName = "mt", icon = icon("user-tie")),
                       selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))   
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.colorme!="green"',
                       menuItem("IRIS", icon = icon("envelope-open-text"), tabName = "ir"),
                       selectInput("irvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
      )
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$colorme,{
    if (input$colorme == "green") {updateTabItems(session, "menume", "mt")
    }else updateTabItems(session, "menume", "ir")
  })
  
  output$mtcarsplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
    
  })
  
  output$mtcarsplot2=renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$mtvar)) + geom_density()
  })
  
  
  output$mtcarstable1=renderTable({
    tabme= head(mtcars, 5)
    tabme
  })
    
  output$irisplot1=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + stat_bin(nbins = 10)
  })
  
  output$irisplot2=renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = input$irvar)) + geom_density()
  })
  
  output$iristable1=renderTable({
    tabme = head(iris, 5)
    tabme
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```